# How to exclude entries with specific value/strings in phpmyadmin SQL?

Tags: sql, phpmyadmin

My DB is collecting relative urls as data. The column is called 'path'. How would I filter out all URLS that have a specific word in phpmyadmin SQL section? Example:

I would like to see all URLs without the word 'coffee' and my path column is full of urls with the word coffee. E.G.

- coffee-is-best
- coffee-in-usa
- cappuccino-right-here
- coffee-mugs-for-sale

So how would I filter out all the 'coffee' urls and only show the one for 'cappuccino'?

SQL:

SELECT * FROM `mytable` WHERE path "What condition/Operator would I use here?"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do it with `NOT LIKE` operator:

```
SELECT * FROM mytable WHERE path NOT LIKE '%coffee%' AND path NOT LIKE '%Beans%'
```

Comment: Thanks! That worked. One more quick question, what would I do if I needed to filter out more than one word? I tries '%coffee%' AND '%Beans%' AND anothercolumn rlike 'someone'. But didn;t return anything.

Comment: Great! Thanks so much! Worked perfectly.